# How can do you install Ubuntu onto a blank Computer using a USB?

Tags: system-installation

I wiped my computer and need to install an OS. Unfortunately my computer does not have a CD drive so I need to boot from a USB. How do you do this?

Comment: Not a duplicate of that @Kaobear, but this question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

You create a live usb from another OS:

Windows - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Ubuntu - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

OSX - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Then you boot your commuter and set your BIOS to boot from the usb first (before the CD or Hard drive). This varies by BIOS and you may have to look thorugh the (BIOS) menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu from a USB-key.

You will need to have :

- another computer with internet access (running Windows, MacOSX or Ubuntu)
- a 1Gb USB storage key (minimum)

Guide for Windows : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
Guide for OSX : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx
Guide for Ubuntu : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Then you can install Ubuntu : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick